# Az Powershell function - how to get output in JSON format

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

I'm migrating / rewriting an azure cli script to Az Powershell.  The current script includes logic like this:

```
#look up the storage account name for this resource group. 
$storageAccount = az storage account list -g $currentEnv.RESOURCEGROUP-o json | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Output $storageAccount.name
```

Is there a way to do this using the Get-AzStorageAccount cmdlet?  (version 4.1.1)

The cmdlet itself works ... I can use it to get the storage account info, but it comes back in table format.  I would like JSON so I can ease the burden of parsing the results.

Comment: Actually `Get-AzStorageAccount` returns an array of [objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.management.storage.models.psstorageaccount?view=az-ps-latest) that just happen to be _formatted_ as table by the default formatter. You don't need to parse anything, you can use dot notation to access properties, e. g. `$storageAccount.id`.

Comment: cool.  if you want to make into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: There should be a space before `-o json`.

Comment: This is just from the docs. I can't really test it, so I suggest you answer your own question. Cheers!

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT yes I was waiting for the person who answered my question to post his / her comments as an answer.  It wasn't yours but zett42's

Answer (score -1):

***If you simply use the below command then you will get the storage account details in a table format which is the default format in Powershell as show in image:***

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
```

[image]

***But this doesn't mean that you can't use a single storage account name or print   selected Paramters .***

**To print the Names you can use the below command :**

```
Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> | Select-Object StorageAccountName
```

[image]

**And the same way you use Az CLI for using the names or a signle name from the list you can use the below commands:**

```
$StorageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
Write-Host $StorageAccount.StorageAccountName
Write-Host $StorageAccount.StorageAccountName[1]
```

[image]